# Function to replace values in data.table using a lookup table

Tags: r, data.table

This a follow-up on this question: [How to efficiently replace one set of values with another set of values in data.table using a lookup table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044480/how-to-efficiently-replace-one-set-of-values-with-another-set-of-values-in-data)

I want to make a function which takes arbitrary data.table `dt`, lookup table `dtLookup` and efficiently replaces (i.e. using data.table in-memory framework) all values in a column `col` according to lookup table.

Here's the original code:

```
  dt <- data.table( chapter=as.character(11:15) );dt

  dtLookup <- data.table(
    old = c("11", "12", "14", "15"),
    new = c("101", "102", "105", "104")
  )
```

This works (original code from post above):

```
  dt[
    dtLookup,
    on = c(chapter = "old"),
    chapter := new
    ][]
```

This however does not work:

```
  dt.replaceValueUsingLookup <- function(dt, col, dtLookup) {
    dt[
      dtLookup,
      on = c(as.name(col) = "old"),
      as.name(col) := new
      ]
  }

  dt %>% dt.replaceValueUsingLookup("chapter", dtLookup)
```

I also tried this:

```
  dt[
    dtLookup,
    on = c(get(col) = "old"),
    get(col) := new
    ]
```

it did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need `as.name`.  Object on the lhs of `=` is not evaluated correctly.  Instead, we could use a named vector in `on` with `setNames`

```
dt.replaceValueUsingLookup <- function(dt, col, dtLookup) {
   dt[
     dtLookup,
     on = setNames("old", col),
     (col) := new
      ]
     }
```

-testing

```
dt %>% 
    dt.replaceValueUsingLookup("chapter", dtLookup)
 
dt
#   chapter
#1:     101
#2:     102
#3:      13
#4:     105
#5:     104
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, *foreign key joins* can also be expressed using the binary operator `==`. Thus, the replacement function can be written as

```
dt.replaceValueUsingLookup <- function(dt, col, dtLut) {
  dt[dtLut, on = paste0(col, "==old"), (col) := new]
}

library(data.table)
dt.replaceValueUsingLookup(dt, "chapter", dtLookup)[]
```

> ```
>    chapter
> 1:     101
> 2:     102
> 3:      13
> 4:     105
> 5:     104
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(chapter = as.character(11:15))
dtLookup <- data.table(old = c("11", "12", "14", "15"),
                       new = c("101", "102", "105", "104"))
```